# What design patterns could be used here?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, python

I'm trying to come up with a nice design (preferably pythonic) for the following use case.

Say there's three services - A, B, C in multiple locations L1, L2, L3, etc. Each service provides different values, e.g. A returns a1, B returns b1, C returns c1.

The task is to periodically run a function that fetches these parameters from all the available locations, does some math (say, sum up) on the values of corresponding services and writes the calculated values back to the services in each location. I.e.

```
for l in locations:
    as.append(getAfrom(l).get_a())
    bs.append(getBfrom(l).get_b())
    cs.append(getCfrom(l).get_c())

new_a = calculate(as)
new_b = calculate(bs)
new_c = calculate(cs)

for l in locations:
    getAfrom(l).write(new_a)
    getBfrom(l).write(new_b)
    getCfrom(l).write(new_c)
```

The above code does this in a very straightforward way (that's probably not that bad), but it fails to scale if the number of services or parameters grows.

What design patterns would make this solution more flexible, extensible (more params, more services)?

Comment: The problem you are having is the performance and not the "I keep repeating the text"?

Comment: Could you please define "pythonic"?

Comment: @MetaFight What I meant was "using the idioms of dynamic languages, such as python."

Comment: ah, ok.  cheers.

Comment: @MichaelT The performance is my main concern, but I'd also like to sketch an extensible architecture. I'm familiar with a few design patterns, and could see some of them (e.g. observer) as a building block for this use case.

Comment: @Sorantis the reason I ask is that GOF isn't so much of "performance patterns" but "architecture patterns".  Performance comes as a side effect of good architecture n those situations.  The specifics of how to improve performance in python are beyond the general GOF patterns.

Comment: @MichaelT I agree. I thought to come out here and ask how would a good approach look like from the architectural perspective, because as you have rightly mentioned, performance is a byproduct of good design.

Comment: It does depend on what you want to generalise and/or which parts of the algorithm are fixed. The obvious adjustment is to abstract the services, allowing inner loops on services and their results. And then, depending upon if your `calculate` will never need to know about the other service values and any sort of "transaction" needed for the `write` calls, you could swap the order of the loops and have a `get; barrier; calculate; barrier; write;` sequence, where either of the barriers may not be needed, depending upon your situation, and error handling.

Comment: What does "it fails to scale if the number of services or parameters grows" mean? Could you write some sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use something like the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), or the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

something like (assuming a few refactors):

```
services = [a,b,c] # add more as needed

accum_strat = lambda l,s: s.Find_Service(l).GetVal()
accum_list = [[] for x in range(len(services))]

for l in locations:
    for srv, lst in zip(services, accum_list):
        lst.append(accum_strat(l, srv)

calcd = [calculate(lst) for lst in accum_list]
write_strat = lambda l,s,v: s.Find_Service(l).write(v)

for l in locations:
    for s,v in zip(services, calcd):
        write_strat(l,s,v)
```

you could even refactor further:

```
def visit_locations(func, args):
    for l in locations:
        for a in args:
            func(l,*a)

services = [a,b,c] # add more as needed

accum_strat = lambda l,s: s.Find_Service(l).GetVal()
accum_list = [[] for x in range(len(services))]
write_strat = lambda l,s,v: s.Find_Service(l).write(v)

visit_locations(lambda l,s,t: t.append(accum_strat(l,s)), zip(services, accum_list))

calcd = [calculate(lst) for lst in accum_list]

visit_locations(write_strat, zip(services, calcd))
```

Adding a new service, one only needs to extend the service list. A new operation adds another visit_locations call, or whatever intermediate needs to be computed.

this could be abstracted further:

```
... 
operations = [lamdba : visit_locations(...),
              lamdba : calcd=...,
              ...
             ]

for op in operations:
    op()
```

Depending on the actual requirements of your system this could be a step too far, or just what is needed for your system. One could do something equivalent but with classes; this exercise will be left to the reader.

N.b. I have conflated the visitor and strategy patterns, IIRC the difference between them is mainly how they are used.

Comment: This is an interesting approach - implementing patterns using lambdas. Thanks!

Comment: @Sorantis you did ask for something pythonic!